# Face detection: detecting multiple mouths in real time OpenCV Java

Tags: java, opencv, webcam, face-detection, haar-classifier

I'm writing a java program using OpenCV that opens the webcam and detects the face, eyes and mouth in real time. Everything works fine except for the mouth detection as it seems to be detecting many mouths all over the face and also appears to be detecting the eyes as mouths. I was wondering why this might be and how I could fix it.

Let me know if you want the rest of the code.

Code for this class:

```
import org.opencv.core.Core;
import org.opencv.core.Mat;
import org.opencv.core.MatOfRect;
import org.opencv.core.Point;
import org.opencv.core.Rect;
import org.opencv.core.Scalar;
import org.opencv.core.Size;
import org.opencv.imgproc.Imgproc;
import org.opencv.objdetect.CascadeClassifier;

public class FaceProcessor {
private CascadeClassifier faceCascade;
private CascadeClassifier eyesCascade;
private CascadeClassifier mouthCascade;

public FaceProcessor() {
    faceCascade = new CascadeClassifier(
            FaceDetector.class.getResource("haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml").getPath());
    eyesCascade = new CascadeClassifier(
            FaceDetector.class.getResource("haarcascade_eye_tree_eyeglasses.xml").getPath());
    mouthCascade = new CascadeClassifier(FaceDetector.class.getResource("Mouth.xml").getPath());

    if (faceCascade.empty()) {
        System.out.println("Face cascade failed to load.");
        return;
    } else {
        System.out.println("Face cascade loaded successfully.");
    }

    if (eyesCascade.empty()) {
        System.out.println("Eyes cascade failed to load.");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Eyes cascade loaded successfully.");
    }

    if (mouthCascade.empty()) {
        System.out.println("Mouth cascade failed to load.");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Mouth cascade loaded successfully.");
    }

}

public Mat detect(Mat inputframe) {
    Mat mRgba = new Mat();
    Mat mGrey = new Mat();
    MatOfRect faces = new MatOfRect();
    inputframe.copyTo(mRgba);
    inputframe.copyTo(mGrey);
    Imgproc.cvtColor(mRgba, mGrey, Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
    Imgproc.equalizeHist(mGrey, mGrey);
    faceCascade.detectMultiScale(mGrey, faces);
    System.out.println(String.format("Detected %s face(s)", faces.toArray().length));
    faceCascade.detectMultiScale(mGrey, faces, 1.1, 2, 0, new Size(30, 30), new Size());
    Rect[] facesArray = faces.toArray();

    for (int i = 0; i < facesArray.length; i++) {
        Point centre1 = new Point(facesArray[i].x + facesArray[i].width * 0.5,
                facesArray[i].y + facesArray[i].height * 0.5);
        Core.ellipse(mRgba, centre1, new Size(facesArray[i].width * 0.5, facesArray[i].height * 0.5), 0, 0, 360,
                new Scalar(192, 202, 235), 4, 8, 0);

        Mat faceROI = mGrey.submat(facesArray[i]);
        MatOfRect eyes = new MatOfRect();

        eyesCascade.detectMultiScale(faceROI, eyes, 1.1, 2, 0, new Size(30, 30), new Size());

        Rect[] eyesArray = eyes.toArray();

        for (int j = 0; j < eyesArray.length; j++) {
            Point centre2 = new Point(facesArray[i].x + eyesArray[j].x + eyesArray[j].width * 0.5,
                    facesArray[i].y + eyesArray[j].y + eyesArray[j].height * 0.5);
            int radius = (int) Math.round((eyesArray[j].width + eyesArray[j].height) * 0.25);
            Core.circle(mRgba, centre2, radius, new Scalar(255, 202, 121), 4, 8, 0);
        }

        MatOfRect mouth = new MatOfRect();

        mouthCascade.detectMultiScale(faceROI, mouth, 1.1, 2, 0, new Size(30, 30), new Size());

        Rect[] mouthArray = mouth.toArray();

        for (int k = 0; k < mouthArray.length; k++) {
            Point centre3 = new Point(facesArray[i].x + mouthArray[k].x + mouthArray[k].width * 0.5,
                    facesArray[i].y + mouthArray[k].y + mouthArray[k].height * 0.5);
            Core.ellipse(mRgba, centre3, new Size(mouthArray[k].width * 0.5, mouthArray[k].height * 0.5), 0, 0, 360,
                    new Scalar(177, 138, 255), 4, 8, 0);
        }
    }
    return mRgba;
}
}
```

Comment: Have you tried [facial landmarks](http://cmp.felk.cvut.cz/~uricamic/flandmark/)?

Comment: @Miki No I haven't - what is that? Does it work with Java?

Comment: Yes, has [Java interface](http://cmp.felk.cvut.cz/~uricamic/clandmark/). It finds facial landmarks: mouth, eyes, nose, etc... and is surely most robust than detecting them individually.

Comment: @Miki Thank you, I'll check it out. But I was hoping to use haar cascades as they're part of a project I'm doing. Do you see anything in my code that could be improved to stop the multiple mouth detections?

Comment: You could put some constraints such as: 1 mouth per face, the mouth must be under the eyes, etc... just guessing, never did this.

Comment: @Miki That's a good point but any idea how to do that?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87513/discussion-between-ini-and-miki).

Comment: Just some simple rules like: "if > 1 mouth, then keep the largest one with y coord > eyes y coord".

Comment: @Miki I'm not really sure how to write that in the code. I'm very new to Java. Would you mind writing some example code?

Comment: did you ever release the code